# Binary to decimal conversion - formula explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, numbers, decimal

can anyone explain me how to see why the number in binary form: 111 is 2^3 - 1 ? 
I know that the number is calculated by 1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^2 but I can't see how to get from here to 2^3-1 ... can't see any power rule or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a unique property of number 2 that the sum of it's previous powers is equal to the next power level subtracted by 1.

In other words:

> 2^n=2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^(n-1)+1 for n in (1,2,3...)

If you need proof, use mathematical induction.

Base: `n=1`; `2^1=2=2^0+1=1+1`

Suppose that for `n=k` the property `2^n=2^0+2^1+...+2^(n-1)+1` is satisfied

For n=k+1 you have `2^n=(2^k)*(2^1)` then apply the hypothesis and you have

`2^n=(2^0+2^1+...+2^(n-2)+1)*2` which yields

`2^n=(2^1+2^2+...+2^(n-1)+2)=1+2^0+2^1+...+2^(n-1)` which concludes our proof.

Answer (score 1):

Add `1` to `111`: the result is `1000`.

It follows, therefore, that:

```
111 + 1 = 1000 → 1000 - 1 = 111
```

Now, `1000` is `23`, hence:

```
23 - 1 = 111
```

Of course, you can say something similar about binary numbers with *any* number of 1s

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this, 111 is 1 less than 1000 (8 in binary).

Answer (score 0):

`0000` is `0`, `0001` is `1`, `0010` is `2`. Depending on the position of the bit from the right side of the binary number, that bit equals to `2^(p - 1)` where `p` is that position.

For example `0010` the `1` is the second bit from the right. `2^(2 - 1) = 2^1 = 2`.

`111` is `2^3 - 1` because `1000` is `2^3` and `111` is *one unit less* than `1000`, therefore being `2^3 - 1`.

By the way, in python you can use `0b` as a token for binary values.

```
x = 0b111
y = 2 ** 3 - 1
print(x == y)
>> True
```

And the `int()` function can be used to convert binary strings

```
x = int("111", 2) # Base 2
y = 7
print(x == y)
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for base B is as follows:

(B^N + ... + B^1 + B^0)*(B-1) =

(B^(N+1) + ... + B^2 + B^1) - (B^N + ... + B^1 + B^0) =

B^(N+1) - B^0 = B^(N+1)-1

Examples:

1. B=2 and N=3 gives 2^4 - 1 = 1111 binary
2. B=10 and N=3 gives 10^3 - 1 = 999 decimal